# When performing mongodb $set on multiple fields, are those fields updated in order?

Tags: mongodb

I need to do a single, atomic update in MongoDB that updates a field based on the existing value in another field, and then updates the second field.  The purpose of this is to update the average voter score of a post when adding a new value, without having to store every vote and re-evaluate them every time.

I found an equation to do this:

```
average = (size * average + value) / (size + 1);
```

Which I then translated into a (somewhat ugly, but hopefully functional) MongoDB update command:

```
{ 
    $set: { 
        'average' : { 
            '$divide' : [ 
                { 
                    '$add' : [ 
                        { '$multiply' : [ 'size' , 'average' ] } , 
                        value 
                    ] 
                } , 
                { '$add' : [ 'size' , 1 ] } 
            ] 
        } , 
        'size' : { 
            '$add' : [ 'size' , 1 ] 
        } 
    } 
}
```

The issue with this is that I must both use the "size" field (the number of votes) to update the "average" field (the average votes) and also increment the "size" field itself afterwards.  What I want to know is, can I be certain that the "size" field will update after the "average" field, or are $set commands carried out in an unpredictable order?

Comment: it will always return an old value if you are using in same stage.

Comment: `$set` will read the values they had before `$set` started(if you add $ that are missing) mongodb has variables also see [$let](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/let/), if you have complicated formulas